# How to display overall furniture dimensions?

Tags: dimensions

This is a follow-up question.  I have enabled "Edge Length" in Viewport overlays, however since the furniture designs I work with consist of many many different parts, enabling "Edge Length" displayed all these parts' dimensions.  The end result was clusters of numbers piled on top of one another.  Please see attachment 1 for visual:[image]

As you can see, the bounding box is not displaying the overall dimensions contrary to my intention.  I used "join" to group all the parts, but apparently, the parts were still treated as individual parts by the "Edge Length" setting.

Is there anyway to get overall dimensions in my scenario?  Please see attachment 2 for my objective.[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Select the object, and in object mode, hit N to bring up a toolbox. Make sure the "Item" tab is selected, and the dimensions are shown at the bottom.

[image: Dimensions Location]

If you want to change the units, click on the Scene button on the right-hand side, and open the "Units" tab.

[image: Units Tab Location]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something similar to the image you hgave as an example, you can make a separate object with just the edges that you need and display edge length on those:

[image]

However that will only work if you are in edit mode of the object.

If you need to make a nice picture with the dimensions showing, it would be best to use MeasureIt addon that can be enabled in the User Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd> → <kbd>p</kbd>), addons tab.

You will have a lot more control on how the dimensions look and will also be able to choose the units without changing your scene's unit settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!